# Cloudflare page rules for removing multiple trailing slash

Tags: cloudflare, trailing-slash

I want to set up the below things in Cloudflare.

`https://example.com//` OR `https://example.com//` OR `https://example.com///` OR onwards

are redirecting to `https://example.com/`

How can I set up this using the Cloudflare page rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be quicker to set that in your webserver(Nginx) virtual host than doing it on Cloudflare.

Add below in your Nginx config:

```
if ($request_uri ~* "\/\/") {
  rewrite ^/(.*)      https://$host/$1    permanent;
}
```